# If InnerBlocks.Content is empty?

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I'm trying to check if `InnerBlocks.Content` is empty, in order to creation a validation to display a `div` when the block is empty or not. It's possible?

I'm using the `npx @wordpress/create-block` tool to create my custom block, and I search and find this:

[conditional layout based on if Innerblocks is not empty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/345220/conditional-layout-based-on-if-innerblocks-is-not-empty)

But I couldn't make it work in this version.

**edit.js**

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

import {
    useBlockProps,
    RichText,
    MediaUpload,
    MediaUploadCheck,
    InspectorControls,
    InnerBlocks,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

import {
    TextControl,
    PanelBody,
    PanelRow,
    Button,
    ResponsiveWrapper,
    __experimentalHStack as HStack,
} from '@wordpress/components';

import { useEffect, Fragment } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

import './editor.scss';

export default function Edit({ attributes, clientId, setAttributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    const removeMedia = () => {
        setAttributes({
            mediaId: 0,
        });
    };

    const innerBlocks_length = useSelect((select) => ({
        innerBlocks_length: select('core/block-editor').getBlockCount(clientId),
    }));

    useEffect(() => {
        setAttributes({ innerBlocks_length: innerBlocks_length });
    });

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody
                    title={__('Imagem/Achievement', 'dt-panphagia')}
                    initialOpen={true}
                >
                    <div className="editor-post-featured-image">
                        <div className="editor-post-featured-image__container">
                            <MediaUploadCheck>
                                <MediaUpload
                                    onSelect={(media) => {
                                        setAttributes({
                                            mediaId: media['id'],
                                            mediaUrl: media['url'],
                                            mediaWidth: media['width'],
                                            mediaHeight: media['height'],
                                            mediaAlt: media['alt'],
                                        });
                                    }}
                                    type="image"
                                    value={attributes.mediaId}
                                    render={({ open }) => {
                                        return (
                                            <Button
                                                className={
                                                    attributes.mediaId == 0
                                                        ? 'editor-post-featured-image__toggle'
                                                        : 'editor-post-featured-image__preview'
                                                }
                                                onClick={open}
                                            >
                                                {attributes.mediaId == 0 &&
                                                    __(
                                                        'Escolha uma Imagem',
                                                        'dt-panphagia'
                                                    )}
                                                {attributes.mediaId != 0 && (
                                                    <ResponsiveWrapper
                                                        naturalWidth={
                                                            attributes.mediaWidth
                                                        }
                                                        naturalHeight={
                                                            attributes.mediaHeight
                                                        }
                                                    >
                                                        <img
                                                            src={
                                                                attributes.mediaUrl
                                                            }
                                                        />
                                                    </ResponsiveWrapper>
                                                )}
                                            </Button>
                                        );
                                    }}
                                />
                            </MediaUploadCheck>
                            {attributes.mediaId != 0 && (
                                <HStack className="editor-post-featured-image__actions">
                                    <Button
                                        className="editor-post-featured-image__action"
                                        onClick={removeMedia}
                                    >
                                        {__('Remove', 'dt-panphagia')}
                                    </Button>
                                    <MediaUploadCheck>
                                        <MediaUpload
                                            title={__('Replace image', 'awp')}
                                            value={attributes.mediaId}
                                            onSelect={(media) => {
                                                setAttributes({
                                                    mediaId: media['id'],
                                                    mediaUrl: media['url'],
                                                    mediaWidth: media['width'],
                                                    mediaHeight:
                                                        media['height'],
                                                    mediaAlt: media['alt'],
                                                });
                                            }}
                                            type="image"
                                            render={({ open }) => (
                                                <Button
                                                    className="editor-post-featured-image__action"
                                                    onClick={open}
                                                >
                                                    {__(
                                                        'Replace',
                                                        'dt-panphagia'
                                                    )}
                                                </Button>
                                            )}
                                        />
                                    </MediaUploadCheck>
                                </HStack>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <PanelRow>
                        <TextControl
                            label="Header"
                            onChange={(heading) => setAttributes({ heading })}
                            value={attributes.heading}
                        />
                    </PanelRow>
                    <PanelRow>
                        <TextControl
                            label="Description"
                            onChange={(content) => setAttributes({ content })}
                            value={attributes.content}
                        />
                    </PanelRow>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>

            <div {...blockProps}>
                <div className="dts-achievement">
                    <hr />
                    <div className="dts-achievement-wrap">
                        <div className="dts-achievement-image-box">
                            <div className="dts-achievement-image-inner">
                                <img
                                    decoding="async"
                                    className={
                                        'dts-achievement-image wp-image-' +
                                        attributes.mediaId
                                    }
                                    src={attributes.mediaUrl}
                                    width={64}
                                    height={64}
                                    alt={
                                        attributes.mediaAlt != ''
                                            ? attributes.mediaAlt
                                            : attributes.mediaTitle
                                    }
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="dts-achievement-content">
                            <RichText
                                tagName="h3"
                                value={attributes.heading}
                                allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/italic']}
                                onChange={(heading) =>
                                    setAttributes({ heading })
                                }
                                placeholder="Enter heading here..."
                            />
                            <RichText
                                tagName="p"
                                className="ts-achievement-description"
                                value={attributes.content}
                                allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/italic']}
                                onChange={(content) =>
                                    setAttributes({ content })
                                }
                                placeholder="Description text..."
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dts-achievement-tip">
                        <InnerBlocks />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

save.js

```
import { useBlockProps, RichText, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function save({ attributes, innerBlocks_length }) {
    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
            <div className="dts-achievement">
                <hr />
                <div className="dts-achievement-wrap">
                    <div className="dts-achievement-image-box">
                        <div className="dts-achievement-image-inner">
                            <img
                                decoding="async"
                                className={
                                    'dts-achievement-image wp-image-' +
                                    attributes.mediaId
                                }
                                src={attributes.mediaUrl}
                                width={64}
                                height={64}
                                alt={
                                    attributes.mediaAlt != ''
                                        ? attributes.mediaAlt
                                        : attributes.mediaTitle
                                }
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="dts-achievement-content">
                        <RichText.Content
                            tagName="h3"
                            value={attributes.heading}
                        />
                        <RichText.Content
                            tagName="p"
                            value={attributes.content}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                {innerBlocks_length > 0 && (
                    <div className="dts-achievement-tip">
                        <InnerBlocks.Content />
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: note that the `useEffect` in the code has no dependencies so there's no way for it to update if the length ever changes. Otherwise this looks like an X Y problem trying to solve an unmentioned problem and you've asked how to implement the solution. If it's what I suspect it is then block templates and the upcoming block hooks would be a superior solution. I also notice that the block props hook is used in the save component, but the inner block props hook is not present, and innerblocks.content is conditionally used

Comment: If the goal is to create a UI similar to how column blocks ask you want when first inserted, I'm not sure why that would lead to change sin the save component though, or why there would need to be an attribute for how many inner blocks there are. Can you provide more context for what you're trying to do that requires this? How would a user in a browser observe the difference?